# Calculus Proof involving exponents.

Tags: calculus, contest-math

Prove that $2015^{2013}<2014^{2014}<2013^{2015}$ without the use of a calculator.

I don't know where to begin here. Any help or guidance on where to begin would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for the first inequality, $x^x=\exp(x\log x)$, $(x+1)^{x-1}=\exp((x-1)\log(x+1))$, which one is bigger?

Comment: I can see intuitively that exp(xlogx)>exp((x-1)log(x+1)). How can I prove this? Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Since $\exp$ is increasing, you need to show $x\log x> (x-1)\log (x+1)$. Note that $2015+2013=2014+2014=:a$, so derivation on $x\log (a-x)$ gives $\log (a-x) -\frac{x}{a-x}$. Note that for the values you are considering $x/(a-x)$ is close to $1$, while $\log (a-x)$ is much larger, so the function is is increasing in $x$ ...